# Select item in dropdown list by taking the text from user

Tags: sikuli

By taking user-input, search for the text in the dropdown. If exists, select it. Else, print: "the text is not present in dropdown".

Comment: What you have tried so far? We are not here to right code for you. If you have a problem with doing this task. Show us what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

In Sikuli, you have 2 ways to recognize textual data:

1. By taking a screenshot of the whole text and creating a pattern.
2. Use built in OCR features to find the text directly.

It is known however that OCR functionality is very limited and not reliable at the moment, hence the preferred solution is to take screenshot of every option you have in your dropdown menu. Then you can just click on the dropdown menu to display the options and then look for your pattern. If the item will be there, you will get a match if not, you know that it doesn't exist.

Assuming you have already saved you text as a pattern in a file, the code will be fairly simple:

```
find("dropDownMenu.png).click()
if exists("menuItem.png"):
    click("menuItem.png") #not very efficient! Left for code simplicity.
else:
    print "the text is not present in dropdown"
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply  . One more query regarding the drop down . There are two pages where in first page he login with his credentials and his credentials is saved in database and in second page in drop down list he have to select his name .               In this scenario how to take the screen shot ??

Comment: @Maheshwari Just do your first scenario manually step by step and take screenshots of the relevant areas, save the screenshots into the folder where Sikuli reads the images from and they are ready to use.